Как с помощь Python и модуля tkinter сделать окно которое будет следовать за курсором?
Мне нужно чтобы окно всегда следовало за курсором как будто оно приклеилось к нему. У меня не получается закрыть окно после функции mainloop().
Вот то что у меня получилось:
import pyautogui
import tkinter as tk

def center_window(width=20, height=20):

    root.resizable(0, 0)
    root.overrideredirect(0)

    current_position = pyautogui.position()
    x = current_position.x
    y = current_position.y
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))


while True:
     root = tk.Tk()
     center_window(100, 100)
     root.mainloop()


Например, так:
import pyautogui

import tkinter as tk

def center_window(window, width=20, height=20):

    window.resizable(0, 0)
    window.overrideredirect(0)

    current_position = pyautogui.position()
    x = current_position.x
    y = current_position.y
    window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))

root = tk.Tk()

window = tk.Toplevel(root)

center_window(window, 100, 100)

def update_position():

    current_position = pyautogui.position()

    x = current_position.x

    y = current_position.y

    window.geometry('+%d+%d' % (x, y))

    root.after(10, update_position)

update_position()

root.mainloop()

